# Add dividend icon in amCharts 5 stock chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to add, in an amCharts 5 stock chart, an icon (a D letter would be more than enough) on the days a quote has distributed dividends. The icon would have a tooltip to show the actual dividend. Something like what yahoo finance has implemented here:

https://finance.yahoo.com/chart/AAPL

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This example has letters D and S on the chart: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/stock-chart/